# Memory usage problem. Game crashes in the actual iPhone

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am developing game for iPhone using Cocos2d, the problem I am having now is the game crashes when it actually runs on the iPhone, but on the simulator is fine. Maybe the game has consume so much memory. Hmm I am thinking that maybe I create so many objects. Such as when the user play, if he makes mistakes, the game display a error subtitle on the screen, and the subtitles are different for each actions the player makes. I don't know the normal way developer use to create subtitles for game in Cocos2D. How do they switch the subtitle easily without consuming huge memory. I am trying the best way to reduce memory usage now. I switched Sprite to AtlasSprite, for timer and point counter I used LabelAtlas too. It still crashes, even though it uses less memory now.

Could anyone give me some good suggestions, like what standard people follow to create games in cocos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, investigate what the real cause is... don't just guess.

Run a debug build on the device, attached to the debugger.  See where the crash is happening in the stack trace.

If you determine it is memory related, then run with insturmentation: object allocation and leaks are the ones you want.